# How to configure Kubernetes liveness, readiness, and startup probes in Go's (GraphQL) gqlgen

Tags: go, kubernetes, graphql, gqlgen

I'm using `Go` and `gqlgen` to implement a GraphQL API. The application will be deployed, eventually, in a `Kubernetes` cluster, so I started looking for a way to configure the usual *liveness*, *readiness*, and *startup* probes.

I've searched for solutions but I haven't found anything that would work without going into extensive lengths and implement this almost by myself.

Is there a way to configure this out-of-the-box using `Go`'s (GraphQL) `gqlgen`?

> I understand this may be outside of the scope of `gqlgen`, but in that case I wonder how people are running their `gqlgen` applications properly with everything that's required, and without starting another web server, etc.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to this interesting project. I've not done any GraphQL but this may be a good time for me to explore it. I had a go at the "Getting Started". From what I can see, you should be able to edit the `server.go` file and add `http.Handler[Func]`'s to implement a simple HTTP handler alongside the GraphQL solution